# HttpURLConnection sending JSON POST request to Apache/PHP

Tags: java, android, ajax, httpurlconnection

I'm struggling with HttpURLConnection and OutputStreamWriter.

The code actually reaches the server, as I do get a valid error
response back. A POST request is made, but no data is received
server-side.

Any hints to proper usage of this thingy is highly appreciated.

The code is in an AsyncTask

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {                                   
    try {                                                                               
        url = new URL(destination);                                                     
        client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();                              
        client.setDoOutput(true);                                                       
        client.setDoInput(true);                                                        
        client.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");   
        client.setRequestMethod("POST");                                                
        //client.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(request.toString().getBytes("UTF-8").length);
        client.connect();                                                               

        Log.d("doInBackground(Request)", request.toString());                           

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream());   
        String output = request.toString();                                             
        writer.write(output);                                                           
        writer.flush();                                                                 
        writer.close();                                                                 

        InputStream input = client.getInputStream();                                    
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));       
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();                                     
        String line;                                                                    

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {                                    
            result.append(line);                                                        
        }                                                                               
        Log.d("doInBackground(Resp)", result.toString());                               
        response = new JSONObject(result.toString());                                   
    } catch (JSONException e){                                                          
        this.e = e;                                                                     
    } catch (IOException e) {                                                           
        this.e = e;                                                                     
    } finally {                                                                         
        client.disconnect();                                                            
    }                                                                                   

    return response;                                                                    
}
```

The JSON I'm trying to send:

```
JSONObject request = {
    "action":"login",
    "user":"mogens",
    "auth":"b96f704fbe702f5b11a31524bfe5f136efea8bf7",
    "location":{
        "accuracy":25,
        "provider":"network",
        "longitude":120.254944,
        "latitude":14.847808
        }
    };
```

And the response I get from the server:

```
JSONObject response = {
    "success":false,
    "response":"Unknown or Missing action.",
    "request":null
    };
```

And the response I should have had:

```
JSONObject response = {
    "success":true,
    "response":"Welcome Mogens Burapa",
    "request":"login"
    };
```

The server-side PHP script:

```
<?php

    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $request = json_decode($json, true);

    error_log("JSON: $json");

    error_log('DEBUG request.php: ' . implode(', ',$request));
    error_log("============ JSON Array ===============");
    foreach ($request as $key => $val) {
        error_log("$key => $val");
    }

    switch($request['action'])
    {
        case "register":

            break;
        case "login":
            $response = array(
                            'success' => true,
                            'message' => 'Welcome ' . $request['user'],
                            'request' => $request['action']
                        );
            break;
        case "location":

            break;
        case "nearby":

            break;
        default:
            $response = array(
                            'success' => false,
                            'response' => 'Unknown or Missing action.',
                            'request' => $request['action']
                        );
            break;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);

    exit;


?>
```

And the logcat output in Android Studio:

```
D/doInBackground(Request)﹕ {"action":"login","location":{"accuracy":25,"provider":"network","longitude":120.254944,"latitude":14.847808},"user":"mogens","auth":"b96f704fbe702f5b11a31524bfe5f136efea8bf7"}
D/doInBackground(Resp)﹕ {"success":false,"response":"Unknown or Missing action.","request":null}
```

If I append `?action=login` to the `URL` I can get a success response from the server. But only the **action** parameter registers server-side.

`{"success":true,"message":"Welcome ","request":"login"}`

The conclusion must be that no data is transferred by `URLConnection.write(output.getBytes("UTF-8"));`

Well, data get transferred after all.

Solution offered by @greenaps does the trick:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request = json_decode($json, true);
```

PHP script above updated to show the solution.

Comment: Show your php script please.

Comment: 'The JSON I'm trying to send:

request = {'. No. Not request but request.toString() should be that. What is the type of 'request'? Do not omit types.

Comment: @greenapps The PHP is quite simple `$request = $_REQUEST;
 $post = $_POST;
 
 error_log('DEBUG request.php: ' . implode(', ',$request));
 error_log("============ REQUEST ===============");
 while (list($key, $val) = each($_REQUEST)) {
    error_log("$key => $val");
 }`

Comment: @greenapps as for the data-types: request is a `JSONObject`. Anything in `"` is a string, anything `true` or `false` is Boolean and so on.

Comment: Do you really have to use "native" HttpURLConnection? There are a lot of useful libraries which make life a lot easier. Want to give it a try? Then I'd give you an example...

Comment: @hgoebl I'm trying to learn this Android stuff, so I think **Going Native** give me the most knowledge.  On the other hand. Looking at alternative ways of doing things, never hurt anybody.

Comment: Please post the php file in a code block. Not in a comment as it is unreadable. Post complete code as this does not output the response you told you got.

Comment: @greenapps PHP and Logcat added to question.

Comment: Start with some php debugging. Add 'var_dump($_POST);' to see what you posted.

Comment: You let php write to an error log file. Much better would be during debug to just echo the key value pairs so you see them in your android client.

Comment: @greenapps I'm doing something similar:  `error_log('DEBUG request.php: ' . implode(', ',$request));`

Comment: @greenapps I have the server log-file in an ssh terminal, so I get the result straight away.

Comment: Yes. But tell us too. You want help isn't it?

Comment: @greenapps  The result of `var_dump($_REQUEST)` is `array(0) {}`  The output from `error_log('DEBUG request.php: ' . implode(', ',$request));` is `DEBUG request.php:`

Comment: And `var_dump($_POST);`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo (file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Will show you the json text. Work with it like:

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

Comment: You are my new hero.

This was what I was missing.

Now I get the propper response:

`{"success":true,"message":"Welcome mogens","request":"login"}`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Below is my answer with Headers and POST Body

Comment: As simple as that. It's been nagging me for hours. I post files for upload no sweat, but getting the json data in php was much easier than I thought. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try to use DataOutputStream instead of OutputStreamWriter.

```
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(_conn.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes(your json serialized string);
        out.close();
```

Comment: Same result. No data reaches the server. Both $_REQUEST and $_POST is empty server-side.

Comment: @MogensBurapa Okay... currently in my application am using this code...    
_conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(this._url).openConnection();
_conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
_conn.setUseCaches(false);
_conn.setDoOutput(true);

and the above code... it works perfectly for me. please try this and let me know

Comment: So, the only difference is the **setUseCaches(false)** Right? Same result. Nothing on the server.

Comment: Same thing here. I've run your code but on a totally different server (not PHP) and it send the data properly. Is there not an issue on the PHP side?

Comment: @JPMoresmau I have added the PHP code, and the logcat output to the original question. Very simple, and working fine from java-script.

Comment: And what does the log on the PHP side say?

Answer (score 1):

I've made server tell me what it got from me.

**Request Headers and POST Body**

```
<?php
    $requestHeaders = apache_request_headers();
    print_r($requestHeaders);

    print_r("\n -= POST Body =- \n");

    echo file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
?>
```

Works like a charm)

Answer (score 0):

> The code actually reaches the server, as I do get a valid error
>   response back. A POST request is made, **but no data is received
>   server-side.**

got this same situation, and come to @greenapps answer. 
you should know what server recieved from 'post request'

what i do first on the server side :

```
echo (file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

then print/Toast/show message response on the client side. make sure its correct form, like :

```
{"username": "yourusername", "password" : "yourpassword"}
```

---

if the response like this (because you post the request with `yourHashMap.toString()`) :

```
{username=yourusername,password=yourpassword}
```

instead using .toString(), use this method instead to turn HashMap into String :

```
private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry :   postDataParams.entrySet()){
            if(first){
                first = false;
            }else{
                result.append(",");
            }
            result.append("\"");
            result.append(entry.getKey());
            result.append("\":\"");
            result.append(entry.getValue());
            result.append("\"");
        }
        return "{" + result.toString() + "}";
    }
```