# Incorrect JSON response from Mapquest - Android App

Tags: android, json

I am trying to obtain a JSON object from mapquest using mapquest api into an Android app. The JSON request specifications are as follows.

```
POST URL:
http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/route?key=[YOUR_KEY_HERE]
POST BODY:   
{
    locations:[
    "State College, PA",
    "Lancaster, PA"
    ]
}
```

The following code successfully makes a connection, But the response from mapquest is incorrect.

```
URL url_mapquest = new URL("http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/route?key=xxxxxxxxxxxx");

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url_mapquest.openConnection();
String urlParameters = "None";
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0");
connection.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT-LANGUAGE", "en-US,en;0.5");
connection.setDoOutput(true);

JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
try {
    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
    list.put("State College, PA");
    list.put("Lancaster, PA");
    jsonParam.put("locations", list);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("JSON String: " + jsonParam.toString());

DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
dStream.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());
dStream.flush();
dStream.close();
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url_mapquest);
System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

final StringBuilder output_Mars = new StringBuilder("Request URL : " + url_mapquest);
output_Mars.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Request Parameters : " + urlParameters);
output_Mars.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Response Code : " + responseCode);
output_Mars.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Type : " + "POST");

String line = "";
StringBuilder responseOutput = new StringBuilder();

if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println("output===============" + br);
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        responseOutput.append(line);
    }
    br.close();
} else {
    responseOutput.append("Response Code 403 Forbidden");
}
```

Below is the incorrect response captured from android emulator

[image]

What might be wrong in the code?

---

**References:**

- [HttpURLConnection sending JSON POST request to Apache/PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680237/httpurlconnection-sending-json-post-request-to-apache-php)
- [JSON.simple example – Read and write JSON](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json)
- [JSON with Java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm)
- [Send HTTP POST Request from Java Application to Google Messaging Service](http://hmkcode.com/send-http-post-request-from-java-application-to-google-messaging-service/)
- [MapQuest Platform Web Services](http://www.mapquestapi.com/)
- [Android weather app: JSON, HTTP and Openweathermap](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/05/build-weather-app-json-http-android.html)
- [Android HTTP Client: GET, POST, Download, Upload, Multipart Request](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/05/android-http-downlod-upload-multipart.html)
- [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: Is there any way you can display the JSON (jsonParam.toString()) you are posting to the api?

Comment: First off it looks like you're not including the required route key, but it would help to see the JSON like Ultradiv asked.

Comment: @Ultradiv the (jsonParam.toString() is {"locations":["State College, PA","Lancaster, PA"]}

Comment: @RScottCarson, I purposely xxxxx out the route key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding the following to connection properties

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

The following comment in the emulator response suggest that the application might not be receiving the JSON object correctly.

```
A JSONObject text must begin with a '{' at character 0
```