# Undefined index, android doesn't send data to php code

Tags: php, android, json

I wrote a program to send `JSON` from my android device to my server (XAMPP). I tested my PHP code using a form and it received the data correctly.

My app, on the other hand, sends no data to my server. Executing `var_dump($_POST)` returns `array(0)` on the server side.

Here's my android code:

```
public BackGround(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params){

    String location_url ="http://192.168.1.90/server_connection.php";
    try{

        URL url1=new URL(location_url);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection)url1.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
       // httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        OutputStream stream_upload=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter buffer_writer=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stream_upload,"UTF-8"));
        String PostData= URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(params));

        buffer_writer.write(PostData);

        buffer_writer.flush();
        buffer_writer.close();
        stream_upload.close();

        int HttpResult = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream stream_dawnload = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream_dawnload, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result = "";
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferreader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferreader.close();
            stream_upload.flush();
            stream_dawnload.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return result;
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

I send the data with this code where `send_json` is my `JSON` object:

```
backGround.execute(String.valueOf(send_json));
```

I think the problem is caused by the `JSON` object not being correctly inserted into the `POST` request body.

I know there are questions with similar issues but none of the solutions helped me.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: are you testing this on localhost ?

Comment: @vikaskumarYes I did.and this eror occured when i tested on localHost.

Comment: are you sure your request is hitting the localhost url. try to be on same network so that request from mobile goes through localhost of your machine.

Comment: @vikaskumar I set this IP for my pc(local server) .my Device and my PC use the same access point.is there any incorrect in my code?

Comment: Improved wording and clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this question's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680237/httpurlconnection-sending-json-post-request-to-apache-php)  I edited my code :
first I eliminate `backGround.execute(String.valueOf(send_json));`from my service   and i sent the vriables as parameters to asyncTask,like below:

```
backGround.execute(String.valueOf(mylocation.getLatitude()),String.valueOf(mylocation.getLongitude()));
```

then in asyncTask class I make my json object.
this is my doInbackground's code:

```
 @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params){


    String location_url ="http://192.168.1.90/connection.php";


try{
        URL url1=new URL(location_url);

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection)url1.openConnection();

        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");



        OutputStream stream_upload=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter buffer_writer=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stream_upload,"UTF-8"));

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    try {
        obj.put("Latitude", params[0]);
        obj.put("Longitude", params[1]);



    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    httpURLConnection.connect();

    buffer_writer.write(obj.toString());
    buffer_writer.flush();
    buffer_writer.close();
    stream_upload.close();





        int status = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
        if(status ==httpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream stream_dawnload = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream_dawnload, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result = "";
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferreader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferreader.close();
            stream_upload.flush();
            stream_dawnload.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return result;
        }


    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;

}
```

and the most important note is that : if u want to send json object to server ,u should add this code :

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

echo (file_get_contents('php://input'));//for being aware of what is in the object.
 $request = json_decode($json, true);
```

and for using json's values:

```
$location_lat=$request['Latitude'];
$location_long=$request['Longitude'];
```

And one thing else,I tryed `$location_lat=$_POST['Latitude']` , and again this error that i asked ,is apeared: Undefined Index.So I resulted for using json objects this method is not correct.
Hope be useful .

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of points here that you should pay attention.

First, as you mentioned, it seems the problem is mainly because your `JSON` data is not being properly formatted into your request. You are passing the data to what seems to be an `AsyncTask` with a `varargs` parameter: `doInBackground(String... params).` This will transform the `String` object you passed when calling `execute(send_json)` into a `String[]` object. Calling `String.valueOf(params)` will not return anything resembling the data you initially passed to the `AsyncTask` but a text representation of a `String` array that contains your data.

Second, I'd strongly suggest you use a 3rd party library to handle the networking code for you. The code you have to write in order to properly manage an `HTTP` connection is neither trivial nor concise. There are much better alternatives out there. [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) is a great example and I'd highly encourage you to use it.

By the way, I'm not discouraging you from knowing how to create and manage `HTTP` connections in java/android. You should definitely try to understand what is going on when you send and receive data. I'm just saying that you don't need to handle all that complexity yourself since there are libraries that do a very good job doing exactly that.

Comment: thank you, I added the answer,If you like,you can check it.